# Rock chips showing magnetic property?

Tags: electromagnetism, geomagnetism

If i am placing two rock(stone) chips closer with a wider area of contact and rotating another rock stone around these two chips(having close contact) for some time (around 30 sec) and try to separate the two stones that i put into contact at first, it seems there is an attraction between the two. Why this is happening? Please explain the phenomenon behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stone contains a ferromagnetic material, which is a material with a spontaneous magnetization. In thermal equilibrium, such a material aligns itself to be magnetized in the same direction. But over a very large distance, you can reduce the bulk energy by randomizing the field direction, so that it pays to put in very large domain walls separating different magnitization regions.

When there is an external magnetic field, it makes the domains line up. The dynamics of the domains is extremely slow, so you end up with a magnetized rock. You are seeing magnetization caused by placing a ferromagnet in the magnetic field of another. You don't need to rotate to see this, just hold them close and wait.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. So the rock is having curie temperature above the room temperature, isn't it? please let me know whether the same property is shown for the other ferromagnetic materials like Fe, Co, Ni etc..

Comment: The Curie temperature is usually a significant fraction of the melting temperature, which for metals is thousands of degrees. The reason is that the electron spin aligning forces are of the same order of magnitude as the solid cohesion forces (a little weaker, but not much). It's surely many hundreds of degrees for everything you listed, although I didn't look it up.

Comment: ""The stone contains a ferromagnetic material, "" How did You find out that? Aside from the very strange description of "magic rotations" I find not hint to ferromagnetism.

Comment: @Georg Here http://www.reference.com/browse/percentage+composition we see that the average rock has about 5% oxides of iron. That is enough for the iron to acquire a magnetization when sitting still for ages, from the earth's field,  and display it  broken in small chips.

Comment: ""that the average rock has about 5% oxides of iron. That is enough for the iron to acquire a magnetization when sitting still for ages, "" This is 1st wrong, and 2nd not at all a clue for ferromagnetism.

Comment: @Georg: The magnetism is the only reason that the rocks would attract. I assumed that one of the rocks is already magnetic, and the other is picking up a magnetization from the other. You find magnetic rocks many places, I assume that anna_v's explanation, that it is aligned by the Earth's magnetic field, is correct.

Comment: You and Anna should refresh info on ferromagnetism, and dont forget to look for ferrimagnetism and which minerals show such behaviour.

Comment: @Georg: I can't refresh, because I never read anything about this in the first place, I don't like reading other people, because I prefer to trust stuff I make up out of my own head. I looked up ferrimagnetism, and it is _completely irrelevant_ , there is no reason to bring it up.

Comment: @Ron-- You explained that if i am keeping the two rocks closer and without spinning anything around it then also the same phenomenon will happen, isn't it? But i am afraid that it is not happening. If it is happening then i think whole ferromagnetic substances will attract each other..Is it so?

Comment: ""I don't like reading other people, because I prefer to trust stuff I make up out of my own head."" I believe this statement is true....

Comment: @Arun: That's interesting--- what is the spinning doing? It doesn't make sense. The ferromagnetism doesn't care about spinning things around far away.